# Invariant Violation: is not usable as a native method argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am new to React Native and I am trying to edit the user's profile. When I open edit profile screen I get this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: [615,"RNDateTimePicker",21,{"testID":"dateTimePicker","height":34.5,"width":138,"alignSelf":"flex-start","date":"<>","maximumDate":2527282800000,"minimumDate":-628477200000,"mode":"date","onChange":true,"displayIOS":"default","enabled":true}] is not usable as a native method argument]

```
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showMode('date')}>
                        <View style={{ width: '100%', borderRadius: 8 }}>
                          {show && (
                            <DateTimePicker
                              testID="dateTimePicker"
                              value={date}
                              mode={mode}
                              minimumDate={new Date(1950, 1, 1)}
                              // maximumDate={moment().subtract(16, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.ssSZ')}
                              maximumDate={new Date(2050, 1, 1)}
                              is24Hour={true}
                              display={'default'}
                              onChange={onChangeDate}
                              style={styles.datePicker}
                            />
                          )}
                        </View>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
```

In internet I have found solutions regarding format but everything I've tried hasn't worked so far. Above is my code if anyone can tell what is going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this looking for a similar problem. It says that the error could be in the format of your date, due the way in which the component expect it

https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/50#issuecomment-566041125

Answer (score 0):

According to the log that you shared it seems the value of onChange is boolean . But according to the documentation it is supposed to be a function that handles the event of date change https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#onchange-optional .